# Does Direct Manipulation API usage require using a Direct rendering backend

Tags: windows, winapi, glfw

I'm writing a app that uses Vulkan/OpenGL for rendering, GLFW for windowing. This does by default does not support precision gestures that modern windows (>8 I guess) supports (as GLFW does not have support for it).

Going trough the Win32 API docs, it seems that to add precision gesture manipulation to win32 apps, one needs to use the [Direct Manipulation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_directmanipulation/). Does this require using a DirectX rendering backend? I've gone through the example app provided [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/TouchInputDirectManipulation), but that uses by default DirectX. I could copy over the framebuffers and whatnot, but was wondering if using DirectX is a *requirement*.

Comment: Manipulation is independent of the presentation. As long as you get access to the window procedure receiving the Direct Manipulation messages, you can combine it with any rendering technology.

Comment: This might be quite an effort, but could you kindly summarize how I'd do that, with a minimal code example? I'm not quire sure how to set this up without using DirextX API

Comment: Direct Manipulation operates on `HWND`'s (see [`IDirectManipulationManager::Activate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directmanipulation/nf-directmanipulation-idirectmanipulationmanager-activate)). You don't need to implement any content rendering for that. [Module 1. Your First Windows Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) explains how to create a window.

Comment: I already have a window, and did activate it, but setting up the context and viewport are what I'm unsure about. I'll give it a try, and report back